# Adding Styling to WooCommerce drop down?

Tags: css, wordpress, colors, woocommerce, styling

Not sure if styling (CSS) is possible w/ this php code, but if anyone knows how i can style this ( with colors, etc) please let me know! this is the basic WooCommerce drop-down code that's placed in my template files

```
<?php  the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Product_Categories', 'dropdown=1' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Plugin :

https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-css-classes/

Please note that this plugin doesn't enable you to enter custom CSS. You'll need to edit your theme's style.css or add another plugin that allows you to input custom CSS.

Refer this for full article

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-styles-to-wordpress-widgets/